# Can you set custom ringtones for contact groups?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, ringtones

In iPhone, you can easily change the default ringtone (Settings → Sounds → Ringtone) and set a custom ringtone for individual people (Contacts → [some person] → Edit → Ringtone).

But can you set a custom tone for a *group of contacts*? (E.g. "family" or "workmates".)

I think that would be handy—and quite *basic* functionality, so to speak—but I couldn't find a way to do this through the iPhone UI. Is it possible at all (without jailbreaking)?

Comment: It had this feature on my 3Gs. I know because I just upgraded to the 4s and it's not there. They changed it.

Comment: Not satisfactory, but noteworthy is the fact that you can left-swipe a conversation and toggle its notifications on/off. I went to http://www.apple.com/feedback/ and submitted a better idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unfortunately not (yet or ever?) officially supported as a feature of iOS.

Comment: Well, that sucks. As you say *yet*, do you happen to know of any evidence that it might be added in a future iOS version?

Comment: No evidence, but Apple has a trend of constantly improving its phone features, as it did when it allowed the sending of a message to multiple recipients, sharing contacts, etc., so we'll just have to be hopeful.

Comment: Though for this specific feature, they haven't added it in any of the last releases. How many releases has there been so far, twenty?! I wouldn't hold my breath. Yet another reason to jailbreak and look for non-Apple-approved hacks.

Comment: What about using a 3rd party app, yet without jailbreaking?

Answer (score -1):

Just use this app: [GRingtones](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/gurupu-zhe-xin-yin-she-ding/id523481550?mt=8), it is a group managing app.

The most important feature is that GRingtones could set a ringtone for each group!

1. Setting a group ringtone
2. Setting a text tone for a group
3. Groups could be created, edited, or deleted free.
4. Searching for contacts is also supported.

Comment: Consider the reviews before buying this app!

Comment: @patrix What do you mean? The reviews are 5 stars... is it some kind of dangerous app? How is it able to do this when everyone says it's impossible?

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak As far as I remember the app didn't really fulfill all the requirements back in 2012. But it seems to have improved significantly since.

Comment: Unfortunately, this app doesn't work on iOS 8.

Comment: Gringtones is no longer working with iOS 9.It was a good paid for ap but it does not work anymore so dont bother with it

Answer (score -3):

yes, you can assign ringtones to contact groups on iPhone using Grouptones tweak ($2.99 in Cydia, requires jailbreak).

See http://grouptonesapp.com for details!

Comment: The question asked for a solution without requiring a jailbreak.

Comment: Answer still helped me, exactly what I was googling for. +1